# Changing storage bus type

Tags: filesystems, fstab

I created a VM on **Fusion** for **OpenStack** — it's a whole thing, not fun at all — which failed to boot once on OpenStack.

OpenStack seems like a pretty rudimentary hypervisor/platform — I think — and I knew the bus type was the issue when I noticed in the original VM that it was set to **NVMe**. I confirmed this later by changing it to the older default of **SCSI** which made the VM fail in the same manner as its cloud-hosted clone. It booted again switching back the bus to NVMe.

It explains why earlier uploads didn't fail too; they were all FreeBSD VMs which never supports the newer options specially for storage. It's kind of ironic FreeBSD being the church/temple-of-worship of almighty ZFS.

## BASICS+PLAN 1: [DISK1]/VOL → [DISK2]/VOL

This is a **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.2** VM, registered, ready to go. I want to avoid recreating it at all costs. I figured I'd just boot from **Fedora Workstation Live** my go-to Live, mount another disk on SCSI and `dd` the volumes or something. It's got LVM (1.`/boot`(XFS), 2.LVM{2.1`/`(XFS), 2.2`swap`}) so it might no be as straightforward as that but at least I had a plan.

Then as I was shutting Fedora down (during the assessment boot with only the original disk attached) on **GNOME**'s ***Disks*** app I caught the path (on `/dev/`) to the volumes that, *being NVMe*, is completely different than SCSI/SATA's. I had forgotten about that.

## PLAN 2: /DEV/PATH-A → /DEV/PATH-B

So, I have a new theory: maybe all I need to do is change the mount points. It'd be so much quicker since once corrected I'd still need to export the VM to OVF, then convert the vDisk to raw making it huge just before uploading it. Thankfully I have a fast uncapped connection but still, transferring eager-zeroed VM disks over the Internet is transferring eager-zeroed VM disks over the Internet.

Better yet: the VM drops me into emergency mode, perhaps I can edit it directly since I have a CLI. Am I onto something?

If this is at all possible, where would that be? **`/etc/fstab`**?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I tried a few things:

- `/etc/fstab` didn't exit at all, I guess because of LVM.
- I explored the LVM route then, so I attempted running `lvm` alone waiting for some error with help, but instead it launched a shell where I did the obvious options, ~view or ~show, ~scan, ~vgchange but none worked because it seems the LVM group wasn't mounted. I don't know how to do that so next.
- I found something about `dracut` but the prompt already read `dracut`, needless to say the command wasn't found. It was ⇥-completed to several hyphenated options, I didn't tried any since it involves booting images, way out of my skills. `mount` showed a lot of info and the OpenStack console sucks, most modifiers won't work. No <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>, or even <kbd>⇧</kbd> and the VM boots on BIOS rather than on bigger-minimum-resolution-requiring-UEFI because OpenStack doesn't have enough wood in the burning chamber to power UEFI, obviously. So the screen is tiny, clumsy and can't fit enough information or move around and layout it changed to top it off, so I was starting to get annoyed and rebooted and…
- I got the GRUB menu and the rescue option booted just fine! Once there I configured the network and SSHed-in to have a full keyboard experience and finally did `dracut -f` hoping it would be enough to recreate the boot information and all that. Nervously I rebooted. It came back online.

All well now, thanks anyway.

**UPDATE 2**

It happened again. Though the VM was already working I recreated it because some unrelated reason. This time I made sure to select SCSI in the bus. Then proceeded with the rest:

> Numbers correspond to related commands for the task, listed at the bottom.

Shut down ***→***  Export OVF/OVA ***→*** Take the disk from the export and convert it to raw (1) ***→*** Uploaded to OpenStack (2) ***→*** Created the new instance (3) ***→*** I went to the console (3), screen was on gray--RHEL's loading bg, press <kbd>esc</kbd> to get the log and there was the error repeating itself over and over.

When it finished and put me in emergency mode I rebooted straight away, selected rescue mode on GRUB and it booted normally same as the past VM. I tried `dracut -f ; reboot`. It rebooted normally this time. I explored a little and noticed that the disks are named starting with a ***V*** instead of **`nvme#n#p#`** or **`sd?#`**.

I may no have the answer but at least I caught the cause, hopefully it's enough to help somebody else.

**EXAMPLE COMMANDS**

1. `qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw "/Volumes/Data/VMs/rhel-9.2/rhel-9.2-disk1.vmdk" "/Volumes/Data/VMs/rhel-9.2.img"`
2. `openstack image create --container-format bare --disk-format raw --file "/Volumes/Data/VMs/rhel-9.2.img" --private --progress Red\ Hat\ Enterprise\ Linux\ 9.2`
3. `openstack server create --flavor varies-per-platform --image "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.2" cloudfront-vm-or-something`
4. `openstack console url show cloudfront`

Comment: Do you get any error message when the launch fails? Do you have access to the cloud's logs? If so, find log entries that contain the failed VM's UUID for more information. Disclaimer: I don't know if and how Fusion differs from "normal" OpenStack.

Comment: Thanks, I sorted out. OpenStack is like a million components none of which providers are req'd to support, docu is super generic and may or may not describe something avail. in your deployment unless ur provider is Red Hat. VMware's 'visors on the other hand, even if older ones are super cutting edge & default to the latest thing they support. So the VM has to be built super generic w/"downgraded" virtual hw, which I did, but I overlooked the disk bus partly because the last VMs I uploaded were FreeBSD systems that also have issues with newer controllers so I had no issues. Lesson learned. :)